# Migrating the website to new url and pointing the old one to the new one

Tags: http, https, certificate, ssl-certificate, redirect

I am about to move my website/App from https://www.example.xx to https://www.example.com 
I am thinking about making a redirection in the .htaccess from the .xx to the .com
The question is shall I renew the https certificate on the .xx bearing in mind that some users might have bookmarks to https://www.example.xx ?

What would happen if a user tries to reach the .xx url on https after the certificate expires and the .htaccess having a redirection to the .com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If application is hosted on the same server (assuming, you just change DNS address for your app) and you own both domains, you would need to purchase single certificate for both URLs: `www.example.tld` and `www.example.com` and bind this certificate to web site.

and you will have to maintain both URLs in the certificate until all users update their bookmarks to point to a new web site.

HTTPS redirection requires valid SSL certificate for all redirection URL.

Comment: the .com and .xx will be on the same server but different IP addresses.